# render HTML (convert to bitmap)

Tags: html, webkit, mozilla, gecko

Can somebody recommend the best (and preferably portable) way to render HTML documents onto a bitmap?  As far as I understand my main 2 options are WebKit and Gecko, but I wasn't able to find a good starting point on how to do it.  When I last tried doing this 5 years ago, I ended up using Gecko to send the document to a printer, which is not really what I need. I need rendering to a in-memory bitmap.

To clarify: server side, no Java, no .NET, batch processing, performance, not interactive, no Javascript.

Comment: This feels like a very ignorant question, but you don't mean just a screen shot?

Comment: see my edit.  server side, non-interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most promising solution I found so far is this 
http://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2
extension for Firefox which adds a command line option for printing a file to a printer, PNG, PostScript or PDF file.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this from the command line using [webkit2png.py](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/), which uses Python and QtWebKit (though I haven't tried it myself yet).

Comment: this is probably very similar to cutycapt which is a Qt-based C++ program using WebKit.  It's sort of good, except dragging all of Qt around for this is kind of sad.

Comment: True, but at least its better than sending it to the printer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146) plug-in for Firefox.