# How to convert html code into jpeg image in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using asp.net and c# in my project and i am trying to translate HTML code into JPEG images .i am creating HTML code but how to translate that HTML code to image .

Comment: What do you mean by "converting HTML code to JPEG image"??

Comment: Your question is not clear at all..

Comment: The OP wants a html file to be rendered and saved as image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [render-html-convert-to-bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632280/)

Answer (score 1):

according to my understanding of your question you want to save html string as any image format. Check the below link . It will be helpful to you

http://forums.asp.net/t/1692392.aspx/1